# .ajax() not sending data to php file

Tags: php, jquery

I am having a problem is retrieving data sent to a php file through .ajax() via jquery

Following is my html:

```
<!-- Jquery tute no 94 onwards -->

<html lang="en">

<head>

<meta charse="utf-8">
<title> jquery4 </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery4.css"/> 

</head>

<body>

<input id="lo" type="text"> </input>
<input id="ton" type="button" value="Load"> </input>
<div id="content"> </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery4.js"> </script>

</body>

</html>
```

My jquery4.js is:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('#ton').click(function()
{ 
    var nm= $('#lo').val();
    $.ajax({url: 'page.php', data1: 'name='+nm, success: function(data2)
    {
        $('#content').html(data2);
    }
    });
});
});
```

My page.php is:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['data1']))
{
    echo $namer= $_GET['data1'];
}
?>
```

All the above files are in the same folder, and I have xampp installed. 
I guess the error is somewhere in the jquery file where I call the 
ajax() function

Comment: Look at your browser's developer tools. Look at the JavaScript console. Does it report any errors? Look at the Net tab. Is the request being made? Does it get a response? Do they contain the data you expect?

Comment: No errors in js file (checked on jsbin)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery ajax doesn't take a `data1` parameter. It takes a `data` parameter, which should be an *object* of name-value pairs.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'page.php',
        data: {
            data1: 'name=' + nm,
        },
        success: function(data2) {
            $('#content').html(data2);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "page.php",
data: {
            data1: 'name=' + nm,
        }
,
        success: function(data2) {
            $('#content').html(data2);
        }

});
```

Comment: Please include some explanatory text to help the OP understand what exactly you are fixing/changing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ton').click(function() { 
        var nm= $('#lo').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'page.php?name=' +nm, 
            success: function(data2) {
                $('#content').html(data2);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

You don't have to tell jQuery to use GET, as it defaults to that, if nothing else is specified.
So the ajax function does not take an argument called data1, but 'data', this is mostly used for other methods as POST, PUT and DELETE.

I prefer also sending GET requests with a normal query string, like the above example.

You can then check for get GET parameter with PHP, using `$_GET['name']`